Android System app, is there a wifi auto accept?
He everyone,
I am working on a system app, and was wondering if there was a WIFI_PRIVILEGE type of functionality like there is for bluetooth to bypass the system dialog that asks to connect.
For bluetooth you can use
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED

and then
bluetoothDevice.setPairingConfirmation(true)

to auto pair bluetooth devices
I was wondering if there was a same functionality for connecting to wifi when the system dialog pops up and asks for permission to connect?
Thank you for your time
